# Single User Authentication with PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

I need to build an extremely simple, single user authentication system. It's for an admin backend, and I only need a single user account to be able to access it. I'd rather not have to create a "Users" database. Since there is only a single user it could even be JUST a password 
(no need for a username).  A javascript alert window would be a nice place to enter this info.

I've seen it before on vendors "Review" servers...how best to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: Most simple would be a `.htpasswd` setup. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each page that needs authentication, you could use the session to see if the user was authenticated or not, and if not, redirect him to the authentication page.

For example, if you had an admin.php page that needed authentication, you could begin with:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (empty($_SESSION['authenticated'])) {
    header('Location: authenticate.php');
    exit;
}

/* rest of the script ... */
```

Then, authenticate.php can be a simple script that asks for the password. If the password is correct (`if ($_POST['password'] == "secret")`), it simply sets `$_SESSION['authenticated'] = true`.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this technique for some admin purpouses:

- Don't create any user account, instead create a database user with the priviledges you need in your admin tasks
- Login at system as your database user and your database password and store these data in a session variable
- Each time you need to access to the database use these variables. If user has not logged with the appropiate credentials will be unable to do anything.

Comment: I actually quite like using real database users for user authentication. Yes, performance suffers, but you gain lots of benefits from database-side access control (including views filtering on username). Certainly not a magic bullet, but can be useful for applications where security is more of a concern than raw performance.

Comment: Isn't this only viable if OP is the DB admin? In a situation where he/she rents web space from a hosting provider, this may not be the case.

Comment: If you give any real user a DB user the response is yes. But if you have just one user (admin) you at least has to had a database user you can use to implement this mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to not create any user table or credentials or sessions or anything, just password protect the directory for admin as mario suggested using .htpasswd

You can use this [tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/htaccess_authentication) for better understanding and easy setup